# Disable Console autocomplete

Tags: firefox, browser, console, autocomplete

When using Firefox with the *Web Console* or *Browser Console*, nearly
everything I type is interrupted by autocomplete.

I do not like this. Sometimes, when I press enter to submit my command, what
actually happens is, my Enter accepts the autocomplete and submits that instead.

If I pay attention, I can press Esc, then Enter, but I dont want to have to do
that. I just want to turn autocomplete off.

Is this possible via some setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see the option presented in the other answer (I am on Firefox 71).

However it seems I actually solved this previously, and must have restored the
default at some point. The settings that controls this are:

```
devtools.webconsole.input.autocomplete
devtools.webconsole.input.eagerEvaluation
```

Comment: I mean the gear button on the top right. But you solved it already so.

Comment: Note: As of Firefox v104, this does nothing unless you completely close and restart the browser (reloading the tab did not work for me). Even then, it will not completely disable auto-complete but I think the 2nd line *does* still have an effect. I tried 2 tests; first, typing typing `foo='` and seeing if it auto-completed the quote. It did **not** disable this behavior (other answer worked fine for this). For test #2, I was pasting the snippet `re = /^\s*Heading.*$/i` and FF would incorrectly try to add 'f' to make "if". After setting `about:config` and restarting, this no longer happened.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Settings" menu in the console toolbar, disable "Enable Autocompletion"